# groupby month-day hour using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

here is what my dataframe looks like:

```
                   user_id  time    hour weekday    location 
updated_at                                          
2019-09-02 05:29:00 29279   5:29:35  5   0            A      
2019-09-02 05:29:00 29279   5:29:39  5   0            A      
2019-09-02 05:29:00 29279   5:29:42  5   0            A      
2019-09-02 05:29:00 29279   5:29:49  5   0            B       
2019-09-02 05:32:00 29279   5:32:28  5   0            C
```

for each day I want hourly sum of rows for each location

*want to achieve something like this `df.groupby(["month-day hour", "location]).count()`

right now I've created additional column that joins month-day hour

```
               user_id  time    hour weekday    location  date-hour
updated_at                                          
2019-09-02 05:29:00 29279   5:29:35  5   0            A       9-2 5
2019-09-02 05:29:00 29279   5:29:39  5   0            A       9-2 5
2019-09-02 05:29:00 29279   5:29:42  5   0            A       9-2 5
2019-09-02 05:29:00 29279   5:29:49  5   0            B       9-2 5
2019-09-02 05:32:00 29279   5:32:28  5   0            C       9-2 5
```

then use `df.groupby(["date-hour", "location]).count()` which seems to do the job however since now index is "month-day hour" format I cannot take advantage of datetimeindex.

if I can't achieve *, how can I change "month-day hour" format to correct datetime.
when I try `pd.to_datetime("9-10 11")` it sees 11 as a year giving me `Timestamp('2011-09-10 00:00:00')`

Comment: can i ask the sum of what? Are you looking for the number of times an hour occurs in the column?

Comment: sum of rows. I've edited it, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the minute and second info from the datetime object. This should do it:

**Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2019-09-02 05:29:00', '29279', 'A'],
 ['2019-09-02 05:29:00', '29279', 'A'],
 ['2019-09-02 05:29:00', '29279', 'A'],
 ['2019-09-02 05:29:00', '29279', 'B'],
 ['2019-09-02 05:32:00', '29279', 'C']], columns = ['datetime', 'user_id', 'location'])
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

print(df.to_string())



             datetime user_id location
0 2019-09-02 05:29:00   29279        A
1 2019-09-02 05:29:00   29279        A
2 2019-09-02 05:29:00   29279        A
3 2019-09-02 05:29:00   29279        B
4 2019-09-02 05:32:00   29279        C
```

**Solution**

```
df['time_hour'] = df['datetime'].map(lambda x: x.replace(minute=0, second=0))
```

**Output**

```
print(df.groupby(['time_hour', 'location']).size().reset_index().to_string())

            time_hour location  0
0 2019-09-02 05:00:00        A  3
1 2019-09-02 05:00:00        B  1
2 2019-09-02 05:00:00        C  1
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need groupby `df.index.floor('H')` and `location`

```
df_out = (df.groupby([df.index.floor('H'), 'location']).location.count()
            .reset_index(1, name='count'))

Out[311]:
                    location  count
updated_at
2019-09-02 05:00:00  A            3
2019-09-02 05:00:00  B            1
2019-09-02 05:00:00  C            1
```